# is there a minimum speed for particles for the double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

I am working on some calculations and seems there must be a cutoff speed for each slit distance for the interference pattern. In other words, for a slit distance of “d” , by reducing the anode voltage ( i.e electrons speed ) the interference pattern should fail to appear below some particles speed or with wider slit distance.  Am I right ?

Is there any paper/ reference doing that experiment out there  ?

Comment: I believe it would  be that the De Broglie wavelength is the likely reason

Comment: Can you provide a condensed version of your calculations?

Comment: like with light waves, if the distance comes in reach of the wavelength you do not see any interference,